# List Organization Unit permissions Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

How can I list all permissions of a Windows Server 2003 Active Directory Organization Unit to file? I need a readeble list in order to compare permissions with another OU of the same domain.

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

dsacls.exe  "distinguishedNameOfOU"

**How to Use Dsacls.exe in Windows Server 2003 and Windows 2000**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281146